# Node.js script to reset mongoDB documents doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have built a game (card game) for which I also collect stats (how many time each card has been dealt, used and won).

After doing some testing, I would like to release it but before doing so, I would like to reset the stats which have been collected while I was testing.

I wrote a script that should do that, but it stops executing after trying to retrieve all the documents. I am getting no errors though, so I am not sure why it isn't working.

** I'm new to Node.js and this is actually my first time trying to write an "independent" script rather than something that is actually part of my backend API, so it's likely something really silly, can't figure out what though.

This is the script:

```
const Answer = require("../models/answer");

const reset = async() => {
    console.log("Reset script has been called");

    try {
        console.log("Entered the try catch block");

        const allAnswers = await Answer.find();

        console.log("before logging all the answers");
        console.log("allAnswers", allAnswers);

        allAnswers.forEach(async(answer) => {
            answer.times_dealt = 0;
            answer.times_picked = 0;
            answer.times_won = 0;

            await answer.save();
            console.log("saved new answer", answer);
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("failed because", e);
    }
};

reset();
```

In my package.json I have it set up like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js",
    "reset-stats": "node src/scripts/reset-answer-stats.js"
},
```

This is my answer model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { answerSchema } = require("../schemas/answer");

const Answer = mongoose.model("Answer", answerSchema);

module.exports = Answer;
```

And this is the schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// This is the schema for an answer object in the DB.
const answerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    body: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
    },

    times_dealt: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    times_picked: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    times_won: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});

module.exports = { answerSchema };
```

My process is that I first run the server `npm run dev` and then in another console I run `npm run reset-stats`.

It prints
`Reset script has been called`

and then
`Entered the try catch block`

And then it just ends. No other logs or any errors.

What wrong?

EDIT:

I've updated my script to use updateMany as suggested but now it fails because it times out. This is my new code.

```
const Answer = require("../models/answer");

const reset = async() => {
    console.log("Reset script has been called");

    try {
        console.log("Entered the try catch block");

        await Answer.updateMany({}, {
            $set: {
                times_dealt: 0,
                times_picked: 0,
                times_won: 0,
            },
        });

        console.log("after updating all the answers");
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("failed because", e);
    }
};

reset();
```

And the error log I get is:

```
failed because MongooseError: Operation `answers.updateMany()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\cards\api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:158:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

I only have like 20 documents on my local environment in this collection (production has hundreds).

I've also tried to write the `updateMany` call like this as I see in some tutorials but it still prints the same error:

```
    await Answer.updateMany({}, {
    times_dealt: 0,
    times_picked: 0,
    times_won: 0,
});
```

Comment: You can run one update query instead of this loop of multiple queries

Answer (score 0):

Try one update query instead of this loop of multiple queries:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
{
  $set: {
    times_dealt: 0,
    times_picked: 0,
    times_won: 0
  }
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yU-20MsC5Zn)

Comment: Thanks Nimrod. I've tried it but now it fails because of an operation timeout? I've added my new code to my post